# Rotate Vector/Point with Python

Tags: python

How can I rotate Vector/Point with python? Could you help me guys?
Here is screenshot:

[image]

On the left - normalized vectors. I need to rotate according to UpVectopr.
On the right - non-normalized UpVector and a point. I need to rotate a point with UpVector.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 10):

A vector has a rotate function - see [`mathutils.Vector.rotate`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_72b_release/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector.rotate)

```
vec = mathutils.Vector((0.0, 1.0, 2.0))
eul = mathutils.Euler((0.0, math.radians(45.0), 0.0), 'XYZ')
vec.rotate(eul)
```